# Assign sql database to an existing sql server elastic pool in ARM template

Tags: templates, arm

Want to create database in existing sql server elastic pool(json outline).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B66iS.png)

Comment: what does this have to do with arm?

Comment: I want to create a database in azure using this arm default template but I am not able to assign that db to existing azure sql server

Comment: 08:43:14 -       "message": "The name 'ameyser' already exists. Choose a different name. ",
,
This error message displays..but I want to add this db into this server
08:43:14 - }'